# I need to push .net 6 specific image to company antifactory and then need to reference it into docker file

Tags: docker, .net-6.0, docker-registry

I have below dockerfile which I am building for .net 6 based application

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS publish
 WORKDIR /src
 COPY ContainerSample.csproj ./

 RUN dotnet restore "./ContainerSample.csproj" --runtime alpine-x64
 COPY . .
 RUN dotnet publish "ContainerSample.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish \
 --no-restore \
 --runtime alpine-x64 \
 --self-contained true \
 /p:PublishTrimmed=true \
 /p:PublishSingleFile=true

 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine AS final

 # create a new user and change directory ownership
 RUN adduser --disabled-password \
 --home /app \
 --gecos '' dotnetuser && chown -R dotnetuser /app

 # impersonate into the new user
 USER dotnetuser
 WORKDIR /app

 # use port 5000 because
 EXPOSE 5000
 COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

 # instruct Kestrel to expose API on port 5000
 ENTRYPOINT ["./ContainerSample", "--urls", "http://localhost:5000"]
```

Here 2 images `sdk:6.0-alpine` and  `runtime-deps:6.0-alpine` I am referencing from `mcr.microsoft.com`.

I need to reference all the image from company antifactory. What's the best way to pull these image and push to company antifactory also how to push most of the settings along with that image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine` to your private repository, you give it a new tag and push it, like this (assuming that your repository is at `artifactory.mycompany.com`)

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine
docker tag mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine artifactory.mycompany.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine
docker push artifactory.mycompany.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine
```

Then you can reference it in your Dockerfile as `artifactory.mycompany.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine`

To create a custom image, you need to create a Dockerfile with the settings you want. Then build it and give it a name that starts with `artifactory.mycompany.com/` and then push it to your company repository.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Kilian. Can we add various settings like `create a new user and change directory ownership`, etc into it and push. I don't want to use all above settings again and again for each app dockerfile

Comment: @user584018 Yes. I've expanded my answer to cover that.